# Video player that can show specific area of video?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player

There are some videos that have a black area/region/section/whatever-its-called in its top and bottom. So, the video can't be played in fullscreen even though it's fullscreen.

Is there any video player can display only the selected area? So the kind of video like i mentioned can be played in real fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC can do this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/13011-vlc-crop-the-playback-window) through the Adjustments and Effects > Video Effects > Crop settings.

[mplayer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPlayerTips#Tip_4:_Using_cropdetect) can also do this. Use something like:

```
mplayer -vf cropdetect=round:16 -ss 10:00 dvd://
```

This will output the detected crop settings in the terminal, something like `720:416:0:80` which can then be used in the crop filter:

```
mplayer -vf crop=720:416:0:80 dvd://
```